# Set Filter and Provided Filter on one column - Ag-Grid

Tags: filter, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag

Is there anyway to get agSetFilter and agTextFilter both on one column of the grid.
e.g. I want below type of filters on one column

TextFilter
[agTextFilter screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf8rP.png)
[agSet Filter screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFwpV.png)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create your own custom filter to handle this:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-custom/